# How to display the list of page numbers using tanStack table in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, html-table, pagination, react-table

I want to implement pagination using react tan Stack table as follow-

< 1 2 3 … 8 9 10 >

Comment: Please share and example with more context.

Answer (score 1):

You can store them in an array

```
const paginationButtons = [];
for (let i = 0; i < table.getPageCount(); i++) {
    paginationButtons.push(
        <button key={i} onClick={() => table.setPageIndex(i)}>
            {i + 1}
        </button>
    );
}
```

Then u can use it

```
 <div>{paginationButtons.map((u) => u)}</div>
```

Having them stored in an array allows You to perform any kind of modification before rendering them.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```js
let paginationButtons = [];
const paginationGoups = [];
const paginationGoupLimit = 10;
const currentPage = table.getState().pagination.pageIndex;
for (let i = 0; i < table.getPageCount(); i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i % paginationGoupLimit === 0) {
        paginationButtons.push(<span>...</span>);
        paginationGoups.push(paginationButtons);
        paginationButtons = [];
    }
    paginationButtons.push(
        <button
            className={currentPage === i ? "active" : ""}
            key={i}
            onClick={() => table.setPageIndex(i)}
        >
            {i + 1}
        </button>
    );
}
if (paginationButtons.length > 0) {
    if(paginationGoups.length > 0) {
        paginationButtons.unshift(<span>...</span>);
      }
    paginationGoups.push(paginationButtons);
    paginationButtons = [];
}
const getCurrentPaginationGroup = () => {
    for (const i in paginationGoups) {
        if (paginationGoups[i].findIndex(u => u.key === String(currentPage)) !== -1) {
            return paginationGoups[i];
        }
    }
};


// You can use it
<div className="pagination">
{getCurrentPaginationGroup().map((button) => button)}
</div>
```

[This looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgtgc.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).